# Emplace back to vector without copying

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a vector of non-copyable objects and I need to use `emplace_back()` to add to the vector. Obviously that gets a error that its trying to reference a deleted function because it is non-copyable. I was just wondering, is there even a way to do this? I am more specifically trying to have a vector of sfml's render windows.

My Main

```cpp
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(100, 100, 32), "Main Window", sf::Style::Default);
    MakeKey MakeKey;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            //Key Presses
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
                    MakeKey.DrawKey("A");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D)
                    MakeKey.DrawKey("D");
                //Ect
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        MakeKey.StepWindows();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My DrawKey Function

```cpp
void MakeKey::DrawKey(string input)
{
    MakeKey::NewKey Key;
    if (input == "A")
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
    else if (input == "D")
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/D.png");
    //Ect
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(Key.Img.getSize().x, Key.Img.getSize().y, 32), "Key", sf::Style::None);
    Key.Tex.loadFromImage(Key.Img);
    Key.Sprite.setTexture(Key.Tex);
    KeyArray.emplace_back(std::move(Key));
    WindowArray.push_back(std::move(window));
    cout << "KeyArray Has " << KeyArray.size() << " Elements\n" << "WindowArray Has " << WindowArray.size() << " Elements" << endl;
}
```

My StepWindows Function

```cpp
void MakeKey::StepWindows()
{
    for (int i{ 0 }; i > KeyArray.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Inside Step Windows For Loop" << endl;
        WindowArray[1].setActive(true);
        WindowArray[1].clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
        WindowArray[1].draw(KeyArray[1].Sprite);
        WindowArray[1].display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that has this issue?

Comment: Preferably as a nice little [mcve] package. It makes it easier for us out here to interpret the full context of your question.

Comment: Vector requires objects to be movable or copiable.  Otherwise, you need an array.

Comment: Most likely you are doing something like `name_of_vector.emplace_back(object_type{arguments});` but what you really want is just `name_of_vector.emplace_back(arguments);`

Comment: @MooingDuck Actually it only requires them to be eraseable.  They only need to be copy/movable if the vector needs to grow.

Comment: If you could loose a little on the emplacement demand: vector of pointers?

Comment: It needs to grow. So how could I go about doing this with a array instead?

Comment: @NathanOliver: "*They only need to be copy/movable if the vector needs to grow.*" That's incorrect. "The vector needs to grow" is a matter of the runtime state of the vector. That *cannot* be determined at compile-time. Statically, `emplace_back` must be *able* to grow the vector, and therefore the `T` stored in the `vector<T>` must be a type which is either copyable or noexcept moveable. Here's the [standard quote](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/sequence.reqmts#tab:containers.sequence.optional): "For vector, T shall also be MoveInsertable into X."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use either `std::vector<T>::push_back()` or `std::vector<T>::emplacy_back()` The type `T` is required to have either a copy constructor or a noexcept move constructor. Please pay special attention that the requirement for the move constructor to be `noexcept` is important: that allows to keep exception safity while the buffer reallocation.

Comment: Only `push_back` has such a requirement.  `emplace_back` was made for cases just like this.

Comment: @NathanOliver that is not right. Both `push_back` and `emplace_back` imply buffer reallocation. This means that the elements have to be either copied or moved to the new location -- no matter how they were added.

Comment: `emplace_back` *may* reallocate, but it doesn't have to.  If you reserve N space up front, you can emplace back N non-copy/movable objects without issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver the same is true about `push_back`: it may reallocate, but is not required to do that. How could compiler know ahead of time whether reallocation would be required?

Comment: so all I need to do is reserve space in declaration?

Comment: @Jacob All you need to do is provide a nothrow move constructor. Reserving space wouldn't help

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov The same is not true for `push_back`.  `push_back` always has to copy or move from the source object.  `emplace_back` on the other have allows you to directly construct the object *in place*.

Comment: @NathanOliver `emplace_back` allows you to construct in place, but that is true JUST for the first construction. If you emplace 1000 elements, sooner or later the buffer has to be reallocated, and the copying/moving would start. Moving may be applied ONLY if it is noexcept.

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry, when I was saying `nothrow` I meant `noexcept`. I still insist on the rest on my words.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The confusion is: Vector `emplace_back` requires a MoveInsertion constructor _in order to compile_. You're right that if you reserve, it will never actually _call_ that constructor, but that doesn't eliminate the requirement for it to exist at compile time.  If you're gutsy you could add a move constructor that just throws an exception, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I do note that another valid answer would be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov "_`emplace_back` allows you to construct in place, but that is true JUST for the first construction. If you emplace 1000 elements ..._" - that's precisely the caveat Nathan mentioned as I understood it. The container is still very useful and I've used this ability with `std::thread`s to make pools a number of times. OP:s question does not go further as I see it. A perfectly forwarding `emplace_back` is nice.